# Load Firebase child name based on corresponding value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to be able to load the value of a firebase child node name. I would like to load the "child name" based on the "child value".

OR if possible, I would just like to be able to load all nodes under the firebase child ID (eg, "20").

This will be loaded into a `recycler view`.

Comment: What do you already know? E.g. Do you know the `Upcoming/Events/03`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I already know that part.

Comment: After writing my answer below, I realized that you're looking for the property name. In that case: do you also know that the value you're looking for is under `20`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, the value I'm looking for will be under `20`... That value is "03/20"

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but why don't you just swap key and value?

Comment: @TranDinhTung is it possible to load all the nodes under `20`?

Comment: If you want all node under 20 then: `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Upcoming/Events/03/20").addValueListener(new ValueEventListener() { .   void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey());}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Upcoming/Events/03");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("Final testing").equalTo("03/20");
query.addValueListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey());
        }
    }
    ...
```

**Update**: If you know the full path to `Upcoming/Events/03/20`, you can do the following to determine the property name that has the value `03/20`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Upcoming/Events/03/20");
Query query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo("03/20");
query.addValueListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey());
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Frank, unfortunately this answer would not be the most efficient as the first node will not always be "Final testing".

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I was wondering if you had any insight on how to load this into a `recyclerview`?